# How do I turn an RSS feed back into RSS?

Tags: python, rss

According to the [feedparser documentation](http://feedparser.org/docs/introduction.html), I can turn an RSS feed into a parsed object like this:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml')
```

but I can't find anything showing how to go the other way; I'd like to be able do manipulate 'd' and then output the result as XML:

```
print d.toXML()
```

but there doesn't seem to be anything in feedparser for going in that direction.  Am I going to have to loop through d's various elements, or is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appended is a not hugely-elegant, but working solution - it uses feedparser to parse the feed, you can then modify the entries, and it passes the data to PyRSS2Gen. It preserves *most* of the feed info (the important bits anyway, there are somethings that will need extra conversion, the parsed_feed['feed']['image'] element for example).

I put this together as part of a [little feed-processing framework](http://github.com/dbr/pyfeedproc) I'm fiddling about with.. It may be of some use (it's pretty short - should be less than 100 lines of code in total when done..)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime

# http://www.feedparser.org/
import feedparser
# http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html
import PyRSS2Gen

# Get the data
parsed_feed = feedparser.parse('http://reddit.com/.rss')

# Modify the parsed_feed data here

items = [
    PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
        title = x.title,
        link = x.link,
        description = x.summary,
        guid = x.link,
        pubDate = datetime.datetime(
            x.modified_parsed[0],
            x.modified_parsed[1],
            x.modified_parsed[2],
            x.modified_parsed[3],
            x.modified_parsed[4],
            x.modified_parsed[5])
        )

    for x in parsed_feed.entries
]

# make the RSS2 object
# Try to grab the title, link, language etc from the orig feed

rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
    title = parsed_feed['feed'].get("title"),
    link = parsed_feed['feed'].get("link"),
    description = parsed_feed['feed'].get("description"),

    language = parsed_feed['feed'].get("language"),
    copyright = parsed_feed['feed'].get("copyright"),
    managingEditor = parsed_feed['feed'].get("managingEditor"),
    webMaster = parsed_feed['feed'].get("webMaster"),
    pubDate = parsed_feed['feed'].get("pubDate"),
    lastBuildDate = parsed_feed['feed'].get("lastBuildDate"),

    categories = parsed_feed['feed'].get("categories"),
    generator = parsed_feed['feed'].get("generator"),
    docs = parsed_feed['feed'].get("docs"),

    items = items
)


print rss.to_xml()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to read in an XML feed, modify it and then output it again, there's [a page on the main python wiki indicating that the RSS.py library might support what you're after](http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) (it reads most RSS and is able to output RSS 1.0). I've not looked at it in much detail though..

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc= minidom.parse('./your/file.xml')
print doc.toxml()
```

The only problem is that it do not download feeds from the internet.

Comment: It doesn't parse them in an RSS-aware way, either; so manipulating the feed will be much harder than with feedparser

Answer (score 0):

As a method of making a feed, how about [PyRSS2Gen](http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html)? :)

I've not played with FeedParser, but have you tried just doing str(yourFeedParserObject)? I've often been suprised by various modules that have **str** methods to just output the object as text.

**[Edit]** Just tried the str() method and it doesn't work on this one. Worth a shot though ;-)

Comment: How would I feed the output of feedparser to PyRSS2Gen?  I tried

    r = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(d)

but that doesn't work.